# Passing javascript array to java form field

Tags: java, jquery, arrays, forms, numberformatexception

I'm using MVC model in java, and I need to pass a List or Array or any kind of data type that allows multiple `String` values (textual, not numeric) from javascript to a java form field.

My `form` implements `Serializable` and have this field

```
private String[] list;
```

with respective getter and setter.

the javascript:

```
var list= new Array(); 
$('#div').each(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        list.push($(this).attr('id'));
        };
    });
$('#result_div').load('mapped_page.htm', {list:list}, null);
```

In debugger mode, just before the load call the list is correctly filled with the selected ids as strings.
When the `list` is empty, the the method mapped by `mapped_page.html` is called and everything is OK, however when the `list` is not empty the method is not called and I have the following error:

```
2013-10-15 15:03:07,856 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/obo].[Flow]] (http-0.0.0.0-8080-2) Servlet.service() for servlet Flow threw exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48) [:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470) [:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499) [:1.6.0_25]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:959) [:3.0.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:921) [:3.0.7.RELEASE]
..
```

what am I missing and what is the best way to pass this element to java form?
I'm not thinking about JSon or similar approaches, just a simple array or list of strings.

Comment: I solved the problem passing a csv string and splitted in java.~
However, suggestions are still welcome